# Translate 'li' one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to move horizontally li elements but not all at the same time like my code does. 
How can I do that?

My code:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('li').css('transform', 'translateX(100px)');
    }, 1000)
})
```

see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4pyd93xh/)

Comment: What is the desired flow?

Comment: Ya, what is your expected behaviour? One after one or randomly moving them???

Comment: One after one any idea plz ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [**each**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function the pass an additional parameter i after that use [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) function to find to current index then move it to left

code:

```
$('button').click(function(){
  $('li').each(function(i){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('li').eq(i).css('transform', 'translateX(100px)');
    }, 1000*i)
  })
})
```

UPDATE: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4pyd93xh/1/)

Comment: The callback to .each() can have a second parameter (let's call it el) that represents the value item at the current index value (which is called i in this case).  So we can make this more efficient by adding the second parameter and replacing $('li').eq(i) with $(el).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't rely on some quite randomized delay, your animations could be out of synch. Use instead relevant event and add specific class, e.g:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $("li").on('transitionend', function(e) {
      $(this).next().addClass('animating');
    }).first().addClass('animating');
  })

});
```

```css
li{
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
li.animating {
  transform: translateX(100px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>List</li>
  <li>List</li>
  <li>List</li>
  <li>List</li>
</ul>
<button>Move</button>
```